# vscode OpenFile dialog window opens in background

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have found multiple [discussions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152179) complaining about OpenFile dialog window of VSCode open in background, so you need to use your mouse pointer to bring it up, which is kind of annoying, but did not found a solution.
Is this a bug or unpleasant feature?
Any solution?

I am using

```
Version: 1.71.2
Commit: 74b1f979648cc44d385a2286793c226e611f59e7
Date: 2022-09-14T21:12:14.256Z
Electron: 19.0.12
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.15.0-48-generic
Sandboxed: No
```

On Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This is the most annoying issue. And this is only on local editing. Remote edits use the menu.  i feel a good workaround would be to make vscode always use the menu rather than the system dialog.

Comment: Actually i found the workaround `settings` -> `file dialog` -> click simple dialog enable. That just opens the menu file dialog

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The workaround I use is this one. vscode opens the dialog for local file edits but uses a simple menu for remote file edits (which avoids the whole problem). So I just set vscode to use simple menu all the time.

I just set the setting  `Files -> Simple Dialog = true`

[image]

Comment: For those using directly a JSON file instead of UI, here's the line you're looking for: `"files.simpleDialog.enable": true`

Answer (score 5):

I figured out how to create a workaround using [this instruction](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2478830&page=2&p=14112414#post14112414)

I created a file `~/.config/devilspie2/code.lua` with the following content:

```
if (get_application_name() == 'code' and get_window_role() == 'GtkFileChooserDialog') then focus_window() center(); end
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the only working solution I have found in over a year.
Shame on vscode for keeping the issue silenced for over a year.

Answer (score 5):

I combined three workaround (including the workaround from and [vladimir ulianitsky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75702366/19152090)) into one answer that fixed this for VSCode Chrome browsers and Typora app that were having this issue for me. All three were necessary for me to fix the issues in my programs.

The one missing from this page for VScode is installing the gnome extension ["Grand Theft Focus"](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5410/grand-theft-focus/) to focus dialog windows for Visual Studio Code.

[Here is a link to the complete three workaround answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1468427/593410)

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I understood that this annoying chrome open file dialog bug is almost the same. So, I modified my devilspie2 config:
`if (get_application_name() == 'xdg-desktop-portal-gnome' and get_window_type() == 'WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG')  then focus_window() center(); end`
I've chosen `get_window_type` because `get_window_role()` is empty

Comment: The extension breaks Telegram Desktop notifications, btw

Answer (score 3):

If you're on `GNOME`, try installing and enable the below extension.

[Grand Theft Focus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5410/grand-theft-focus/)

Comment: Faster, easier working solution in Manjaro 11/2023

Answer (score 2):

It is an upstream issue and I am facing the same. The best-known solution to me is to downgrade the vscode from `v1.71.2` to `v1.67.2`

No fix has been made to date as mentioned [here.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146422)

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround to run the latest version 1.72.2 on ubuntu 20.04 with on openFile dialog **in foreground** (to date the bug is still not fixed) is to add the environment variable GTK_USE_PORTAL=1 when running vscode, in your bash:

```
> GTK_USE_PORTAL=1 code
```

Also, you can create a new desktop launcher, that you can add it to your task bar, in `~/.local/share/application/vscode.desktop` :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=VSCode
Comment=Code Editing. Redefined.
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=env GTK_USE_PORTAL=1 /usr/share/code/code --unity-launch %F
Icon=com.visualstudio.code
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Code
Categories=TextEditor;Development;IDE;
MimeType=text/plain;inode/directory;application/x-code-workspace;
Actions=new-empty-window;
Keywords=vscode;

[Desktop Action new-empty-window]
Name=New Empty Window
Exec=env GTK_USE_PORTAL=1 /usr/share/code/code --new-window %F
Icon=com.visualstudio.code
```

Comment: This does not work for me.  As always the initial open dialog after vscode starts will be in front, But after that it always opens in background. its the most annoying thing in vscode because you have to use the mouse several times to get the file open.